# How can I draw a surface plot by matlab via 3 matrixes of data?

Tags: matlab

I have 3 series data : 
a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3];b=[52.97,52.92,51.78,55.66,50.45,50.23,53.02]; c=[0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.5];

I wanna draw a surface by MATLAB via these data (C vs A and B); how can I do that?

When I use the  "[A,B,C]=meshgrid(a,b,c);surf (A,B,C) ", I will have an error by MATLAB. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `griddata()` could be helpful. This function does interpolation of scattered points in 3D space. Here is an example of the usage applied to your example with three vectors `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
%generate a new mesh over coordinates a and b
st_a=(max(a)-min(a))/50;
st_b=(max(b)-min(b))/50;
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(min(a):st_a:max(a),min(b):st_b:max(b));

%do interpolation for c over the new mesh
vq = griddata(a,b,c,xq,yq);

%plot the surface
surf(xq,yq,vq)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your help was nice. I use "[A,B]=meshgrid(a,b);C=griddata(a,b,c,A,B); surf(A,B,C) ", but the resulted plot is not good, that is not a good surface :(. How can I get a good surface?

Comment: Try different interpolation methods in the function griddata(a,b,c,A,B,'method'), where method can be specified as linear, cubic, natural, nearest, v4 More info is in the matlab's help for griddata() Here I would suggest 'nearest'

Comment: Thanks again. I saw only "linear, cubic, natural, nearest, v4" in matlab's help. These methods cannot get a good surface. Are there another method?

Comment: Play with the mesh. In my example I set the regular mesh taking minimal and maximal elements from your a and b vectors and specify the step 50.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `scatteredInterpolant` to not only interpolate your data, but also extrapolate it too. However, you don't have enough data points to get meaningful interpolation/extrapolation.

```
a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3].';
b=[52.97,52.92,51.78,55.66,50.45,50.23,53.02].'; 
c=[0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.5].';

F = scatteredInterpolant(a,b,c);

da = (max(a)-min(a))/100;
db = (max(b)-min(b))/100;

ta = min(a):da:max(a);
tb = min(b):db:max(b);

[aq,bq] = meshgrid(ta,tb);
cq = F(aq,bq);

figure
mesh(aq,bq,cq); 
hold on; 
plot3(a,b,c,'o'); 
hold off;
```

Comment: Did you mean TriScatteredInterp ? My version of matlab does not have scatteredInterpolant .

Comment: I cannot mean TriScatteredlnterp, too :(

Comment: Does this class belongs to some toolbox?

Comment: I solve my problem as below:  
st_a=(max(a)-min(a))/50;
st_b=(max(b)-min(b))/50;
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(min(a):st_a:max(a),min(b):st_b:max(b));
vq = griddata(a,b,c,xq,yq,'v4');
surf(xq,yq,vq)